# Nested ordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, sublist

I need a nested list with subitem numbering, like this:

```
1. Item 1
  1.1 - Subitem 1
  1.2 - Subitem 2
  1.3 - Subitem 3
  1.4 - Subitem 4
  1.5 - Subitem 5
2. Item 2
  2.1 - Subitem 1
  2.2 - Subitem 2
  2.3 - Subitem 3
  2.4 - Subitem 4
  2.5 - Subitem 5
```

Well, I know I cannot achieve that with pure HTML. It would be great to use something like this and have the sublist automatically numbered:

```
<ol>
<li>
   Item 1
   <ol>
     <li>Subitem 1</li>
     <li>Subitem 2</li>
     <li>Subitem 3</li>
     <li>Subitem 4</li>
     <li>Subitem 5</li>
   </ol>
</li>
<li>
   Item 2
   <ol>
     <li>Subitem 1</li>
     <li>Subitem 2</li>
     <li>Subitem 3</li>
     <li>Subitem 4</li>
     <li>Subitem 5</li>
   </ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Is there a solution for this using JavaScript or jQuery or something?

Comment: While you can't get "dotted hierarchical numbering" like you describe with pure HTML, you can change the numbering style for each level (number, uppercase letter, lowercase letter, greek symbol, etc). And that might be good enough, depending on your need.

Comment: Thanks, darkporter, I know that, but what I really need is a subnumbered list that carries its parent number and a dot separator. Abraços.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it cross-browser with jQuery:

```
$("ol#list ol").each(function(i, el){
   $(this).children().each(function(ci,cel){
      $(this).prepend('<span class="pseudo-num">' + [i + 1, ci + 1].join('.') + ' </span>');
   });
}).addClass('pseudo-processed');
```

And in your CSS:

```
ol .pseudo-num { display: none }
ol.pseudo-processed { list-style: none; padding-left: 0 }
ol.pseudo-processed .pseudo-num { display: inline; font-weight: bold }
```

This is for one level only. You could alter the code to create a recursive function for multiple levels.

This is setup to progressively enhance your page. Without Javascript it would fallback to normal nested numbering.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to *@Gumbo* work, I reworked this code into a recursive plugin. It would use the same CSS as in my previous example, but now it is a "full fledged" jQuery plugin with support for any depth:

```
$.fn.outline = function(options, counters){
    var options  = $.extend({}, $.fn.outline.defaults, options),
        counters = counters || [];

    this.each(function(){
       $(this).children('li').each(function(i){
           var ct = counters.concat([i + 1]);
           if(counters.length){
             $('<span></span>')
                .addClass(options.numberClass)
                .text(ct.join('.') + ' ')
                .prependTo(this);
           }
           $(this).children('ol').outline(options, ct);
       })
    });

    if(!counters.length) this.addClass(options.processedClass)
}

$.fn.outline.defaults = {
       numberClass: 'pseudo-num',
    processedClass: 'pseudo-processed'
}
```

You could then call it on a specific `#id`:

```
 $("#list").outline();
```

Or use @Gumbo's nice selector to apply it to all `ol` tags on one page:

```
 $("ol:not(li > ol)").outline();
```

And you can either override the defaults globally, or on an individual basis:

```
 $.fn.outline.defaults.processedClass = 'ol-ready';
 // or
 $("#list").outline({processedClass: 'ol-ready'});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, this did work! The javascript solution is still better because of the lack of support for the pure-css solution in browsers.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this was really helpful (the multi-depth code rewritten). I wonder if other webmasters have the same need for this sort of list... I believe so. Abraços.

Answer (score 8):

You can use CSS to do so:

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counter(item) ". - "; counter-increment: item }
LI LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " - "; counter-increment: item }
```

But it requires support for [`counter` and `counters`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters).

---

**Edit**    Here’s a jQuery approach similar to dcneiner’s but with no limitation to depth:

```
function foo($ol, counters) {
    counters = counters || [];
    $ol.each(function(i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.children("li").each(function(i) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.prepend(counters.concat([i+1]).join(".") + " ");
            $this.children("ol").each(function(j) {
                foo($(this), counters.concat([i+1]));
            });
        });
    });
}
foo($("ol:not(li > ol)"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I picked the one above because of the cross-browser compatibility. Thanks.

Comment: Like the refactoring... I am going to try to rewrite yours now... you gave me an idea...

Comment: OK, took the basic idea of your code (loved the `concat` to copy the array and add the number!) and turned it into a jQuery plugin. Its in my answer now. Thanks for taking the time to improve this!

Comment: @Marcos Buarque: I don’t see why his first verson would be more cross-browser compatible than mine.

Comment: Ooops, the first time you posted, it was pure CSS. Am I wrong? Anyway, thank you for all the help...

Comment: @Marcos Buarque: Yes, it was. And then I added the jQuery example inspired by dcneiner’s first approach.

Answer (score 4):

Neither js nor jquery but CSS:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
    UL, OL { counter-reset: item }
    LI { display: block }
    LI:before { content: counters(item, "."); counter-increment: item }
</STYLE>
```

More here: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#lists