# Creating divs with numbers

Tags: html, css

Probably i would like to build a logic for an "numbered" div list.

Like the function from Microsoft Word where you can make some numbered lists like

1. FOO
2. FOO
   2.1 FOO
   2.2 FOO
   2.3 FOO
3. FOO
4. FOO

now I'd like a function that creates me several DIVS with position numbern.
if it is now deleted number 2, the position numbers of all other DIVS be adjusted and the same if a div is shifted up or down.

would be great if someone could show me the right direction

regards.

ps: i attached a image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKMRx.jpg

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a "do this for me" website. This site is for solving specific problems you have.

Comment: now im stuck here.. i provided an "example" how it should looks like below.. http://jsfiddle.net/V6Kj7/10/

Comment: ok i found an solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852816/nested-ordered-lists , thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4):

The correct tag for this task is `ol`, as `div` would be un-semantic, and a javascript numbering mechanism would be less portable, slower, and heavier, as `ol` was specifically created for the task

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: A simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/4sQK2/1/

Comment: can i get the current position of an <li> entry? .. i fill the "divs" with different content. when i delete an <li> entry, can i traverse the list and refresh the position list?

Comment: Yes. First, get the list (`ol`) with a selector like `getElementById` or whatever, and then access its `childNodes` property, which returns a `nodeList` object, a method of which is `item`, which retrieves the nth element in the nodelist. Example: `document.getElementById('id').childNodes.item(5)` to get the fifth one. hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

try this (i hope it helps you)

http://jsfiddle.net/V6Kj7/

HTML:

```
    <ol>
    <li>item 1
        <ol>
            <li>sub item 1
                <ol>
                    <li>sub-sub item 1</li>
                    <li>sub-sub item 2</li>
                    <li>sub-sub item 3</li>
                </ol>
             </li>
             <li>Sub item 2</li>
         </ol>
     </li>
     <li>item 2</li>
 </ol>
```

CSS:

```
        ol { 
        counter-reset: section;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ol li { counter-increment: section; }
    ol li:before { content: counters(section, ".") ". "; }
```

Browser Support: http://caniuse.com/#search=counter-reset