# Recursive bullet style on nested ordered lists

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have ordered lists automatically styled based on its level as such:

```
1. Item
  a. Item
    i. Item
      1. Item
        a. Item
          i. Item
           ...
```

As you can see it is repeating this sequence: `number > letter > roman numeral`

I can do this through CSS as

```
ol {
    list-style-type:decimal;
}
ol > li > ol {
    list-style-type:lower-alpha;
}
ol > li > ol > li > ol {
    list-style-type:lower-roman;
}
ol > li > ol > li > ol > li > ol {
    list-style-type:decimal;
}
...
```

but this is tedious and I don't know how many levels I would need.

**Is there a cleaner way of doing this through CSS?**

I should note that I am doing this to style up an HTML editor and the generated HTML has this very basic structure:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>
        ..
```

I have no control of the HTML and I can't add classes to it or anything.

Comment: Did [any of these solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852816/nested-ordered-lists) work for you?

Comment: @adm looks like OP wants pure css.

Comment: @admdrew Preferably a CSS only solution. No SASS or LESS either.

Comment: You don't use any styles on `li` so you can use `ol/ol ol/ol ol ol/ol ol ol ol`, without _direct child_ selector.

Answer (score 5):

It's not the prettiest solution, but we've decided to go with this one for now:
<sub>Thanks to @Vucko for suggesting that we didn't need the *direct child selectors*</sub>

```
ol,
ol ol ol ol,
ol ol ol ol ol ol ol {
    list-style-type:decimal;
}
ol ol,
ol ol ol ol ol,
ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol {
    list-style-type:lower-alpha;
}
ol ol ol,
ol ol ol ol ol ol,
ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol {
    list-style-type:lower-roman;
}
```

This obviously works only up until the 9th level, but we don't think any list will go down this deep for our scenario.

<sub>*If only there was some sort of `:nth-level()` selector...*</sub>